# Javascript: How to determine the screen height visible (i.e., removing the space occupied by the address bar etc)

Tags: javascript

As asked in the question, how do I find out the screen space available for the webpage through javascript?

Comment: removing the space occupied by the tabs on top and all. just the screen real estate (if i may) available.

Comment: Cross browser solution needed?

Comment: yeah. that would be great. or ill end up serving only a few people, and leaving the rest to complain that i am a novice (although i am)

Comment: so basically what you're after is the client size?

Answer (score 7):

window.innerHeight