# What JavaScript method can I use to find the height of the page on different screens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a document and I am trying to find the height of the page on different screen sizes. For example In the code below I am trying to make a button that when clicked takes you back to the top of the page, when you get to the bottom of the page it appears and when you get past a certain height it disappears. Can anyone help please.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollFunction);

            function scrollFunction() {
                if (window.pageYOffset > 300) {
                    backToTop.classList.toggle("show");
                }
            }
```

```css
.back-to-top {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 15%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 3px darkgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0, 0);

    transition: opacity 250ms ease-in, transform 250ms ease-in;
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
                <div class="back-to-top">
                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get div height with plain JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript)

Comment: The code and question doesn't seem to be very related to the title...  Have you looked at [How to determine the screen height visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377782/javascript-how-to-determine-the-screen-height-visible-i-e-removing-the-space)

Comment: have a look at this link... https://stackoverflow.com/a/8876069/1533592

Answer (score 0):

To get the page height you can use `document.body.clientHeight`. To check if the user arrived to the bottom of the page you can subtract the page height from the window height `document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight`

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollFunction);
            
            function scrollFunction() {
                if (window.pageYOffset > (document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight)) {
                    var backToTop = document.querySelector('.back-to-top');
                    backToTop.classList.toggle("show");
                }
            }
```

```css
.back-to-top {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 15%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 3px darkgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0, 0);

    transition: opacity 250ms ease-in, transform 250ms ease-in;
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}

.top-container{
height:1000px;}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
                <div class="back-to-top">
                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
```